# grub2 not looking for config file in /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

When I try to boot, it goes into grub command line (repair mode). If use the configfile command to point to the config file, the system immediately boots with no problem. SO it seems clear that grub is not looking for the config file in what I believe is the correct location: /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

I have printed out the config file and it does not appear to be corrupt. Also the system boots successfully when I manually point to this file. So why cannot grub find it at boot time?

It is my understanding that if it boots into grub "rescue" mode then that means that it cannot find grub.cfg. If I undrestand correctly, failure to update grub.cfg would not produce this behavior. Also, I have since run grub-mkconfig and I still get this behavior.

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  Is this UEFI or BIOS boot. If BIOS, you may have old grub in MBR. If UEFI, you may have incorrect UUID in /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg.

Comment: It is UEFI. Yes, the UUID in /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg is incorrect and maybe the drive identifier as well. I would like to follow your instructions to use "ppa version" but I don't know how. I have never heard of ppa. I get my live boot from a Linux install flash drive. The second option is to install Linux.

Comment: @oldfred True, in my case (BIOS) I'd to re-install grub to update the MBR code where probably the location of grub.cfg is hard-coded

Comment: Since Microsoft required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives in 2012 with release of Windows 8, few systems are still BIOS. And systems prior to 2012 need a lightweight flavor of Ubuntu, not Gnome based Ubuntu. A ppa is an easy way to install software, but you only want to use ones that are trusted.

Answer (score 1):

As @oldfred said, the UUID in the config file under EFI was incorrect. I put in the correct UUID and now it boots cleanly!

Comment: That probably means your grub did not fully install or installed somewhere else? I have that issue as I install multiple test versions and newest overwrites grub in ESP. I learned just easier to edit grub back to main working install than totally reinstall grub from that install. Then I add to my 40_custom to boot newest test install.

Comment: In my case, in /etc/fstab, the uuid with the vfat option was not the first one...

Answer (score 0):

When you change the content of grub config file, you need to "rebuild" it using grub-mkconfig.

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: But I never changed any configuration fies. Did the system change it?

Answer (score 0):

`grubia32.efi` looks for `grub.cfg` using a variable called `prefix`

If `($prefix)/grub.cfg` does not exist, you’ll get the grub prompt.

This is why the `configfile` GRUB command works because you are overriding the use of $prefix (provided you are not using this variable!)

## Context

I am working with an old 2007 MacBook that requires a 32-bit EFI. The latest installs of Ubuntu (20.04 and 22.04) and distros derived from them (eg. elementaryOS 7.1) unfortunately no longer include the files required to rebuild the machine from scratch (as I found out the hard way when my machine wouldn’t boot).

So I took `BOOTIA32.EFI` from [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html) and it included grubia32_real.efi (which I renamed to `grubia32.efi`) and I got to the GRUB prompt.

I discovered the `configfile` GRUB command workaround to manually get to the GRUB menu and also became quite stumped why GRUB wasn’t finding grub.cfg on its own. Where is this defined I thought to myself?

Then I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1768654/238572) and what seemed like a complete aside ('Fun' with grub rescue>) was a goldmine. I used the `set` command in GRUB to dump the contents of all its variables and that’s when I realized prefix is set to `(hd0,2)` in the “real” grubia32.efi. My grub.cfg is sitting in partition 4 in `(hd0,gpt4)/boot/grub`

So I went on another witch hunt and found [AIO-Boot](https://github.com/nguyentumine/AIO-Boot) which has a custom version of grubia32.efi whose prefix is `(hd0,gpt1)/AIO/grub`

I put this custom version of grubia32.efi in `/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT` and put a copy of my grub.cfg in `/boot/efi/AIO/grub/grub.cfg` and BAM! my machine brings up the GRUB menu and I can dual boot Linux distros!

Out of curiosity, I tried to move my install to gpt2 (2nd partition) and for some reason the “real” grubia32.efi still won’t work even if I put my grub.cfg at `/grub/grub.cfg` (apparently `prefix=(hd0,2)/grub` is not the same as `prefix=(hd0,gpt2)/grub`)

My install boots with AIO-Boot and while I will need to remember to copy grub.cfg to the AIO directory after an `update-grub`, this isn’t going to happen too often as this machine is on its last legs!

Hope this helps someone out there trying to keep perfectly usable old hardware out of our landfills!